# Match from the second occurrence to the end of a string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to bulk replace strings using notepad++ but can not seem to get the regex right.

Below are two rows

```
(405, 1, 1, 'AWESOME', 1, 752, 1, 753, 1, '[{"id":1,"left":1,"right":714,"title":"Department"},{"id":405,"left":752,"right":753,"title":"CHANGE THIS TO AWESOME 1"}]'), 
(406, 1, 1, 'MO IS AWESOME', 1, 754, 1, 755, 1, '[{"id":1,"left":1,"right":714,"title":"Department"},{"id":406,"left":754,"right":755,"title":"RANDOM STRING NEEDS CHANGING"}]'),
```

I'm trying to change the second title value in the json on each row, but the regex below matches the first title to the end of the json

```
(title.*?)"(.*?)"\}\]
```

This regex selects the following line

```
title":"Department"},{"id":405,"left":752,"right":753,"title":"CHANGE THIS TO AWESOME 1"}]
```

instead of

```
title":"CHANGE THIS TO AWESOME 1"}]
```

The example strings to be changed are

```
CHANGE THIS TO AWESOME 1` and `RANDOM STRING NEEDS CHANGING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the title, even more important than what the entire regex matches is what the second capture group is matching. In your example, the matches are

```
Group 1.    74-79   `title`
Group 2.    80-161  `:"Department"},{"id":405,"left":752,"right":753,"title":"CHANGE THIS TO AWESOME 1`
```

The problem is that the lazy possessive is evaluated forwards. Ie, the regex begins matching at the first `title` and from there tries to find the sortest string that matches, but it has to include the entire line because of the terminating `"\}\]`

The optimal solution depends on if there are any irregularities in your data.

The easiest solution for the examples you gave is probably `title":"([^"]*)"\}\]`, but it only works if titles never contain a quote character and title is always the last attribute in the line

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `title.+?"title":"\K[^"]+`
- Replace with: `REPLACEMENT`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
title       : literally title (ie. the first one in the line)
.+?         : 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
"title":"   : literally
\K          : forget all we have seen until this position
[^"\r\n]+   : 1 or more any character that is not double quote or line break
```

**Result for given example:**

```
(405, 1, 1, 'AWESOME', 1, 752, 1, 753, 1, '[{"id":1,"left":1,"right":714,"title":"Department"},{"id":405,"left":752,"right":753,"title":"REPLACEMENT"}]'), 
(406, 1, 1, 'MO IS AWESOME', 1, 754, 1, 755, 1, '[{"id":1,"left":1,"right":714,"title":"Department"},{"id":406,"left":754,"right":755,"title":"REPLACEMENT"}]'),
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this will solve your problem :

```
(?:\"title\".+?)(title.*?)"(.*?)"\}\]
```

[View the regex match here](https://regex101.com/r/mZJsap/1)

Comment: This seems to still be selecting the first occurrence.

Comment: @mk_89 did you check the group 2 match.

Comment: Using an anonymous capturing group does no good when the goal is to replace part of the string. If you drop the `?:` at the beginning, you can use this regex to replace by using the replacement string `$1$2"REPLACEMENT_TEXT"}]`. It still matches from the first `title`, but the data is retained in the replacement.

Comment: @Cephalopod You are right, i think if i don't use a non capturing group there we can use a match replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
(?m)(?<=title\":\")[^\"]*(?=\"[^\n\"]*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/87)